# Pass parameters to a query Access VBA

Tags: ms-access

This question has been asked previously. I adjusted my code (below) based on what I understood from research on this topic. However, my code breaks down on line in bold below.

I have a form (`PBCIncSum`) where the user can input the start and end date criteria for a query `RstName`. This function is to calculate the 95th percentile values for the data that is in query `RstName`. When I run the code I get a run-time error '3061: Too few parameters. Expected 2. What am I doing wrong? Spent three days staring at this code without any solution.

```
Public Function PercentileRst(RstName As String, fldName As String, PercentileValue As Double) As Double
 'This function will calculate the percentile of a recordset.
 'The field must be a number value and the percentile has to
 'be between 0 and 1.
 If PercentileValue < 0 Or PercentileValue > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Percentile must be between 0 and 1", vbOKOnly
 End If
 Dim PercentileTemp As Double
 Dim dbs As DAO.Database
 Set dbs = CurrentDb
 Dim xVal As Double
 Dim iRec As Long
 Dim i As Long
 Dim RstOrig As DAO.Recordset
 Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
 Dim prm As DAO.Parameter

 Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs(RstName)
 qdf.Parameters(0) = Forms!PBCIncSum!StDate
 qdf.Parameters(1) = Forms!PBCIncSum!EndDate

 For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
      prm = Eval(prm.Name)
 Next prm

 **Set RstOrig = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(RstName, dbOpenDynaset)**
 RstOrig.Sort = fldName
 Dim RstSorted As DAO.Recordset
 Set RstSorted = RstOrig.OpenRecordset()
 RstSorted.MoveLast
 RstSorted.MoveFirst
 xVal = ((RstSorted.RecordCount - 1) * PercentileValue) + 1
 'x now contains the record number we are looking for.
 'Note x may not be     whole number
 iRec = Int(xVal)
 xVal = xVal - iRec
 'i now contains first record to look at and
 'x contains diff to next record
 RstSorted.Move iRec - 1
 PercentileTemp = RstSorted(fldName)
 If xVal > 0 Then
    RstSorted.MoveNext
    PercentileTemp = ((RstSorted(fldName) - PercentileTemp) * xVal) + PercentileTemp
 End If
 RstSorted.Close
 RstOrig.Close
 Set RstSorted = Nothing
 Set RstOrig = Nothing
 Set dbs = Nothing
 Set qdf = Nothing
 PercentileRst = PercentileTemp
```

End Function

Comment: I have a follow-up question. How do I calculate the percentile for only non-NULL or non-ZERO values?

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are trying to use `CurrentDb.OpenRecordset` to run the query. You have created the QueryDef object `qdf` and defined its parameters, so you need to use the `OpenRecordset` method of that QueryDef object:

```
Set rstOrig = qdf.OpenRecordset
```

Comment: Gord,
Thanks for your quick reply. When I do what you suggested, it gives me the following error on the same line:

run-time error '3001':
Invalid argument.

Sunil.

Comment: I tried the following code and it worked!!! Thanks for your help!!! :-)

Comment: Set rstOrig = qdf.OpenRecordset()